# How can I hide and show my menu with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this script that changes a CSS property in my nav when I scroll down. (It changes after 100px.)

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {    
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
         //console.log(scroll);
        if (scroll >= 100) {
            //console.log('a');
            $(".header").addClass("change");
        } else {
            //console.log('a');
            $(".header").removeClass("change");
        }
    });
```

How can I hide the nav at some point of the scroll (1000px) and show it again after that section (1500px)?

Comment: You want to show the `nav` only when the `scrollTop` value is **exactly** `1000px` and `1500px`?

Comment: did you see the answer I gave @Mauro

Comment: If you're using jQuery, please tag the question as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this something you want done ? https://jsfiddle.net/znw67k79/3/

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var myScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (myScroll == 1000){
    $('nav').fadeOut('slow');
  }
  if (myScroll == 1500){
        $('nav').fadeIn('slow');
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work. please review it

```js
if (scroll >= 1000 && scroll <= 1500) {
  //console.log('a');
  $(".header").hide();
} else {
  //console.log('a');
  $(".header").show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For handling scroll, delaying invoking handler is a way to avoid unnecessary intermediate calls when the scroll is in progress:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>hide and show my menu with JavaScript</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .header
        {
            min-height: 50px;
            position: fixed;
        }

        .header li {
            float: left;
            list-style: outside none none;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }

        .content {
            height: 10000px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(document).bind('scroll', function (e) {
                clearTimeout(this.scrollTimeout);
                this.scrollTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
                    var currentTop = $(e.target).scrollTop();
                    console.log(currentTop);
                    $('.header').toggle(currentTop < 1000 || currentTop > 1500);
                }, 500);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
            <li>Item 5</li>
            <li>Item 6</li>
            <li>Item 7</li>
            <li>Item 8</li>
            <li>Item 9</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```